# oboe.js - pattern to select specific node rather than all matching?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON array I'm getting via an http stream.  Simplified, the objects are structured like this:

```
{
  "ID" : 1234,
  "Item" : {
    "ID" : "ABC123",
    "name" : "a thing"
  }
}
```

The objects are in an array, so in reality I'm getting:

```
[{"ID":1234,"Item":{"ID":"ABC123","name":"a thing"}},{"ID":5678,"Item"....]
```

I'm using [oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/) to parse the stream as it arrives and use the `ID` to do some other things, but I'm having difficulty distinguishing `ID` from `Item.ID` in the object.  For example, this snippet will match both `ID`'s:

```
oboe(res).on("node", { "ID": function (id) {
        console.log("found thing with ID of " + id);
}});
```

Output confirms that it's grabbing both `ID` values instead of just the first, which is what I need:

```
found thing with ID of 1234 
found thing with ID of a thing
```

I tried using the following patterns, with no success:

- `ID` - matches both
- `!.ID` - matches neither
- `*.ID` - matches both
- `.ID` - matches both
- `ID.` - matches both

**tldnr: I'm struggling to find the right pattern that says "match a node named `ID` off the root of an object in the stream and ignore any others in that object".**

Comment: By "off of the root" do you mean a root property of the object? Or a non-root property? If you mean root property, shouldn't `!ID` work? If not, then maybe `!*.ID` would work?

Comment: Added clarification about it being an array of objects rather than just one object...AND `!*.ID` worked.  Throw that into an answer and I'll approve it.  I see the problem now.  Thanks for the nudge.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment for the OP's question: `!*.ID` should match a node object `ID` property within an array.